# How can i scroll to specific ID using Header?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Like the link : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type 
Here when you open this link, Window will automatically scroll to the `type id`.
How did they do it?
I mean, how to scroll to a specific id on the same page using Header like `some.com/post/#id`
Please comment below if you need more clarification.

EDIT 2 :
Okay `home.php#26` this is working..
But this is working only wen the page is already loaded and then i change the header.. i want it to work when page is loaded First time with this url only.

Like when u open http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type It automatically takes you to id "type". But when i load mywebsite/home.php?#26 it does nothing.

Comment: take a look at jquery.scrollTo()

Comment: just put ur code on fiddle.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {  
    window.location = '#26';
 });

Comment: Please look at the comment on the answer below.. "#26" is a variable which is changing through php. It is not fixed.

Comment: it will be helpful if u post some code also.

Comment: Can you please avoid using the [header tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/header?sort=newest&pageSize=50), It's deprecated now.

Comment: there is any div in ur page with id 26?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use headers, first include in the target GET variable to id where you want to scroll to.

Eg - `/home.php?target=12` (12 is the id here)

Then use the following script:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#<?php echo $_GET['target'];  ?>').offset().top - 100 }, 'slow');
});
```

Here you go with Your scroll plus cool jQuery effect. :)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to provide an id at the end of the url .

like `yoursite.com/page/#yourid`.

somewhere in your site `<div id="yourid"></div>`.

And you are done, this doesn't animates the scrolling, if you want animated scrolling use , jquery `animate` function.